# Default django object to be used as a base

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one

I'm trying to set up a site on which members of a team can create games which can have a variety of settings (things like the maximum number of players).

The team will have a settings object which will contain default values for these settings but the users can change these values for each game if they like (without affecting the team's defaults).

I'm wondering what the best way to set this up is. So, given the following model:-

```
class GameSettings(models.Model):
    max_players = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    etc.
```

should I

a) add a one-to-one relationship to GameSettings to both the Team and the Game model, like this:-

```
class Team(models.Model):
    gamesettings = models.OneToOneField(GameSettings)

class Game(models.Model):
    gamesettings = models.OneToOneField(GameSettings)
```

or

b) add 2 one-to-one relationships to the GameSettings model, like this:-

```
class GameSettings(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, null=True)
    game = models.OneToOneField(Game, null=True)
    max_players = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    etc.
```

The most sensible solution seems to be a) but if I go for that then I need to somehow copy the Team's gamesettings whenever a new Game is created. But how?

Or does b) make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Game settings seem like they should be kept as simple as possible, then it will be easy to use a method to create a copy (and the model will be easy to test):

```
class GameSettings(models.Model):
    max_players = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    ...

    def override(self, **overrides):
        vals = {f: overrides.get(f, getattr(self, f)) for f in self_meta.get_all_field_names()}
        return self.__class__.objects.create(**vals)
```

Creating a new Game then becomes:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    default_team_settings = models.ForeignKey(GameSettings, related_name="+")

class Game(models.Model):
    default_game_settings = models.ForeignKey(GameSettings, related_name="+")

myteam = Team.objects.get(..)
newgame = Game.objects.create(
    default_game_settings=myteam.default_team_settings.override(max_players=2, ...),
    ...
)
```

This should also be easier to test since it will be easier to mock the `GameSettings` members from Game/Team than the Game/Team members from `GameSettings` (since `GameSettings` is deliberatively kept simple in this version).  I've disabled reverse relations on the fkeys to enforce this simplicity.

Comment: The idea would be to use the Team's settings whenever a new Game is created and then allow users to update those (copied) settings if necessary. So really, you're just using the override method to mean "copy", aren't you?

Comment: in terms of `dict` semantics it would be a copy + update operation, in terms of the implementation it's creating a new object with values from `self` except as specified by `**overrides`.